# get_queryset en Django

Tags: python, django, djangorestframework

Estoy trabajando con rest framework y necesito retornar un count a partir de una consulta, el caso es que me produce un error, el cual dice que el objeto no es iterable.

Segun la documentacion, get_queryset() solo devuelve lista consultas (que son iterables, lose), pero en mi caso debo retornar un count() de esa lista, ya que necesito devolver el numero de likes que tiene un objeto en especifico.

**Explico el codigo**

modelos:

```
class Opinion(models.Model):
     id_user = model.ForeignKey() #su respectiva tabla 
     id_business = model.ForeignKey() #su respectiva tabla
     like = model.BooleanField(default=False)
     dislike = model.BooleanField(default=False)
```

```
class OpinionView(mixins.ListModelMixin,
                        viewsets.GenericViewSet):

       serializer_class = OpinionSerializer
       

       def get_queryset(self):
           likes = Opinion.objects.filter(like = True).count() #el resultado es un int
           dislikes = Opinion.objects.filter(dislike = True).count() #el resultado es un int

           return likes #o dislikes
```

```
TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable
```

El caso es que no puedo retornar los valores   `like y dislike`. Espero que se entienda el problema,
Muchas gracias por adelantado!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si te das cuenta estas heredando de un mixin **mixins.ListModelMixi**n y estas haciendo un override al metodo **get_queryset()** que necesita el metodo **list** de dicho mixin:

Te recomiendo que mejor utilices **viewsets.ModelViewSet** que proporciona varios métodos básicos (CRUD) de esta manera:

```
class OpinionViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Opinion.objects.all()
    serializer_class = OpinionSerializer
```

Luego creamos un metodo personalizado (lo que quieres hacer)

```
@action(detail=True, methods=['get'], url_path='opinion-likes')
    def opinion_likes(self, request, pk=None):
        likes = Opinion.objects.filter(like = True).count()
        dislikes = Opinion.objects.filter(dislike = True).count()
        return Response(likes)
```

(Si deseas le puedes pasar parametros desde tu cliente para que reciba si quiere mostrar los likes o dislikes)

y se accedería de esta manera a este api -> nombredeturul/opinion-likes/

Comment: Muchas gracias, me ha servidor, tan solo use viewsets.GenericViewset en ugar de ModelViewSet ya que por algun motivo no  funcionaba, pero muchas gracias, la clase GenericsViewset si me deja devolver int !!

Answer (score 0):

No entiendo si tu error es precisamente en esta linea: `likes = Opinion.objects.filter(like = True).count()`, necesitaría más detalle de no ser así. Se me ocurren varias formas, sin revisar detalladamente el problema que tienes con el .count(), te comparto dos:

1. Mandar una raw query con un count:
   `Opinion.objects.raw('SELECT count(likes) FROM my_database')`

La segunda, hacer algo como `len(likes)`

Comment: muchas gracias!, el problema estaba en que al user la funcion get_queryset() de  mixins.ListModelMixin  solo podia devolver querys y yo queria devolver un .count() el cual es un int , de todas formas la respuesta de abajo es la que he implementado